# Confusion with installing different ruby gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed `rubygems-1.7.2` but then out of some confusion with not being able to install rails  when I ran this command:

```
gem install rails
```

and I got this error:

> ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>         bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6

That is a bit strange since the rubygems I have on my system is a much later version.  Do I maybe need to configure it somehow so that my shell recognizes it?  What is a step I might be missing to have this resolved?

I have

```
/usr/local/rubygems-1.7.2
```

was it supposed to get installed in a different directory or something?

Comment: How did you install the newer version? What do you see if you type `gem --version`? (Also I think you mean 1.6.2.)

Comment: @Telemachus I don't exactly remember how I installed it since it was yesterday, but I definitely have rubygems-1.7.2

Comment: Please post the output of `gem --version` to be sure everything went ok with your Rubygems install.

Comment: For some reason the output is "gem --version" is 1.3.5 - but that is the confusing part: I was trying to install the 1.7 version :)

Comment: Should I do some sort of a purge of the 1.3.5 version and then do an apt get for 1.7.2 version?  What would be the right command/syntax to get the 1.7.2 version?  Thanks!

Comment: To install RubyGems, download the source tarball from rubyforge (http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubygems/).  Unpack it and in a terminal run the command `ruby setup.rb install`.

Comment: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/12 try the environment variables in the list esp. GEM_HOME. i think its just the repository home, and not the gem application, yet its worth a try. else, find the gem binary, and add the path to your PATH variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing RVM made it unnecessary to install RubyGems separately...I think :)